# Access object from multiple React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, javascriptmvc, mapbox-gl-js

I have a `MapboxMap` React component that initialises and renders a Mapbox map (under the `map` const), and needs to render `MapMarker` components inside of it.

This is what `MapboxMap` looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import MapMarker from './MapMarker'

const MapboxMap = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount(argument) {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'access_token'
    // This is what I want to access from inside of <MapMarker />
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this),
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8',
      center: [-74.50, 40],
      zoom: 9
    })
  },

  render() {
    const errors = this.props.errors
    const photos = this.props.photos
    return (
      <div className='map'>
        {errors.length > 0 && errors.map((error, index) => (
          <pre key={index}>Error: {error}</pre>
        ))}
        {errors.length === 0 && photos.map(photo => (
          <MapMarker key={photo.id} photo={photo} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

module.exports = MapboxMap
```

This is what `MapMarker` looks like.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import MapboxMap from './MapboxMap'

const MapMarker = React.createClass({

  render() {
    const photo = this.props.photo
    console.log(photo)
    // I want to be able to access `map` inside of this component
    return (
      <div className='marker'></div>
    )
  }

})

module.exports = MapMarker
```

How can I structure my two components so that I can access `map` from both components, but specifically render the map inside of the `MapboxMap` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `map` variable in some other Lifecycle method like `componentWillMount()` or `componentWillReceiveProps()` and assign the value of map to `this.state` via `setState()` method.

eg:

```
state = {map: {}}                           // defined a default state
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  map =  new mapboxgl.Map({ //your code });
  this.setState({ map: map});
}
```

Now, pass `this.state.map` as props to child MapMarker. Inside your `render()` method in `<MapboxMap/>`,

```
<MapMarker key={photo.id} photo={photo} map={this.state.map}/>
```

Now inside `<MapMarker/>` component the map from your parent `<MapboxMap/>` component will be accessible as `this.props.map`.

PS: Refer [Component Specs and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) from React Docs for understanding where to use `setState()` method and where not.

Answer (score 3):

Naisheel Verdhan's approach is good. I'd make one suggestion on top of that. Instead of setting the state in `componentWillMount()` or `componentWillReceiveProps()`, you can do it in `getInitialState()` (`React.createClass` syntax) or in the constructor() (ES2015, `class extends React.Component` syntax).